# PYTHON crop image based on black location

Tags: python

I am trying to crop images that will remove as much possible black. the images are random and the black is not always in the same place:
[DICOM image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIFjC.png)

my region of interest is shown in blue...this image is oriented to the right but other images have different orientation.
I tried the following but it is returning an empty image:

```
enter codeimg = cv2.imread('F:/Jad Breast/S10460/S711091/I1030.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,120,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours,hierarchy =         
cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = contours[0]
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
crop = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('F:/S10460/S711091/sofwinres12.png',crop)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?